# Is there python Function to remove word between special character and space

Tags: python, string, nlp

I'm trying to remove the `*@hmo2406*` word using the below function. Could you check and help me?

```py
'*@hmo24* وين هل الغيبه  '

>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\n@.*?\n','',a, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: something like this? `re.sub(r'^@\S+\s+', '', a)` (assuming `a` is your string). this reads "string that starts with a @, followed by at least one NON whitespace character, followed by at least one white space character"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're removing non-Arabic characters from your string then try this:

```
import re 

text = '*@hmo24* وين هل الغيبه  '

arabic_string = " ".join(re.findall('[\u0600-\u06ff]+', text))

print(arabic_string)
```

**Output:**

```
وين هل الغيبه
```

Comment: Yeah, it hopefully that helped :)